# Get result back after form submit

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I need a quick help.

I want users can upload a csv file. Then I do some parsing and meaningful things with the file in the back. Finally, display the results back to users. When they upload the file, I would like to check to see if the file size is <= 250kb or contains <= 1000 lines.

In JSP:

```
<form action="/Project/CSVUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br />
<input id="uploadfilebutton" type="file" name="file" class="tss-btn tss-btn-blue" accept=".csv" required />
<br />
<input id="processfilebutton" type="submit" value="Process File" class="tss-btn tss-btn-blue" />
</form>
```

So there is an upload button and a submit button. How can I get a status back after users click the submit button? For example, if the process fails I want to display an pop up error message.

In JavaScript:

```
function process()
{
$.ajax({
    url:"/Project/CSVUpload",
    type:'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(soapContents){

        if (soapContents.haserrors)
        {
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Process File Failed',
                message: soapContents.returnmessage,
                buttons: [ {
                    label: 'Ok',
                    action: function(dialogItself){

                        dialogItself.close();
                    }
                }]
            }); 
        }

    }
});
}
```

This works when I don't use form. The form is required because enctype has to be like that.

In Java:

```
@WebServlet("/CSVUploads")
public class CSVUpload extends HttpServlet 
{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException 
{
boolean hasErrors = false;
if (CSVUpload success) // assume we get the info from CSVUpload class
{
    hasErrors = true;
}
if (hasErrors)
    {
        log.error("CSVUpload: "+returnMessage);

        // Setup JSON response. 
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        jsonObjectBuilder.add("haserrors", hasErrors);
        jsonObjectBuilder.add("returnmessage", returnMessage);
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectBuilder.build();

        // Write the JSON out as a response. 
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.print(jsonObject);
        printWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

So I made some changes and add a new java class to handle the ajax query... it submits twice, first submit is getting the form info and second submit is checking for a success... I don't know if anyone has better idea, but this is what I change to make it work. It sounds not a good idea, but it works for now. If anyone has better idea please let me know, a working sample will be great.

Comment: change type="submit" to type="button" will get the json return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use button instead of submit. It is because submit type input is submitting the form, but you also send request using ajax. That's the reason of two requests.

Comment: Okay, let me try. Thanks for your respond.

Comment: you meant type="button" not type="submit"... now I get it... thanks